# pasing json using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following JSON code. How do I parse using JavaScript or jQuery an convert to variables: `name`, `meetup`  tags ?

Here is my code:

```
{
    "MYID": 1,
    "module": [
        {
            "name": "Manchester",
            "meetup": "First Monday of every month",
            "tags": [
                "gtug",
                "google",
                "manchester",
                "madlab"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "jQuery Group",
            "meetup": "First Tuesday of every month",
            "tags": [
                "jquery",
                "javascript",
                "jresig",
                "madlab"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Hybrid!",
            "meetup": "First Monday of every month",
            "tags": [
                "jquery",
                "javascript",
                "jresig",
                "madlab"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(your-json-here)`

Comment: @GlenSwift Not sure if the primary question is to parse the json, or retrieve the variables from inside the array of objects as the title and body text conflict...

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will answer your question?

```
var json = JSON.parse("...");
for (var i = 0; i < json.module.length; i++) {
    var mod = json.module[i];

    var name = mod.name;
    var meetup = mod.meetup;
    var tags = mod.tags;
}
```